# Anchoring a label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am relatively new to WPF and trying to insert a label computed by an algorithm inside a panel. I create the label in my code. I do not use the designer for the label.

The problem is that when I add the label to the panel, it gets resized when I resize the Window. I want the label to be a fixed height and width. Apparently it is anchored to the bottom of the window (I know that from the usual Winforms behavior).

How can I unanchor it, or give it a fixed size?

***EDIT***

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWrapper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyTest" Height="483.833" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Margin="0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Background.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
 if (!_initialized)
 {
    Label lbl = new Label()
    {
       Content = "Test",
       FontSize = 36,
       Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
       Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
       HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
       VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top
    };
    this.MyGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
    lbl.Margin = new Thickness(0, this.MyGrid.ActualHeight + lbl.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
    this._initialized = true;
 }
```

Comment: It's not anchored to the bottom of the Window (nothing you know about Winforms layout behaviour applies here); it's being laid out by its parent control. What's your full Xaml?

Comment: Actually it might be because I change the margin. It might be an error in the code. (My XAML does not define anything. There is just a grid there.)

Comment: So are you adding the label to your grid in code? Whatever it is you're doing, share the code/markup...

Comment: You still need to post the XAML when asking a question. so long as label width height are not defined they will not size with parent control and pos will remain at x,y from top left if parent is grid. If your familiar with HTML think of it as a DIV with absolute at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was in a margin calculation. I repaired it. Anyways now I posted the code and maybe you can still find something wrong with it, despite everything is working now. As I said I am not familiar with the WPF ways of doing things yet. There will be multiple labels added over time, every time an event is raised (like a button click, or from an other hardware part like a sensor).

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to hardcode a width and height, explicitly set the `Width` and `Height` attributes of your label:

```
<Label Width="100" Height="20">Hello World</Label>
```

A `Grid` will automatically centre and stretch its children, given no other information, and this is the default behaviour you're likely seeing.

(If you provide more code/markup, I can give a more detailed explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use instead the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`.

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Hello World" />
```

In this way, the label is automatically centered and the size is dynamically adapted by the WPF Engine.

Remember also that a WPF interface should not be developed by code behind, in most of cases, if not always. You can easily use the Xaml to resolve your problem.

Comment: But I actually want to "scroll" the labels from the bottom of the grid. That means I would have to position the label on the bottom of the grid and move it up as soon as a new label appears. (This is animated, I can not just dock them bottom)

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't understand you, but if you want, you can manipulate animations with WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.